# Different ways to vertically align in CSS

Tags: css

I'm a bit confused about various options to vertically align elements. I've read through several posts which explain each of the options stand-alone, but failing to find anything that explains the different use cases of each.

In particular, what are the differences between the following, when to (not) use them, and why?

1. align-items: center;
2. vertical-align: middle;
3. margin: auto 0;

Also, it seems that in many cases there needs to be a fixed height defined and display set to flex to make the alignment work, which is not good for responsive design. How can this be avoided?

Comment: Umm... Vertical or horizontal? Coz 1 and 3 are horizontally centering ones.

Comment: @PraveenKumar 1 is for flex, it's not text-align. I misread that at first as well

Comment: all of them are vertical. horizontal would be justify-content: center

Comment: @PraveenKumar i think 3 can be used for a flex item, should have the same effect as 1 but I never tried it so don't take my word for it

Comment: align-items goes for flex and grid, margin:auto 0, goes also for flex and grids and can also go with absolute, vertical-align goes with table cell(html or css display) and for inline-/inline-block elements.... any of these rules works with others within a layout method.

Answer (score 1):

The first one `align-items: center` is used with `display: flex`. This aligns all children elements vertically.
Second one `vertical-align: middle` can be used in two contexts:

- to vertically align an inline element's box inside its containing line box. For example, it could be used to vertically align an `<img>` in a line of text:
- to vertically align the content of a `cell` in a `table`

Third one `margin: auto 0` works only if you have margins on top and bottom side (does not mean that they need to be specified, what I mean is, you cant center span or any other inline element with `margin: auto 0`).
Using `flex` in my opinion is the best option and its definitely not bad for responsive design. And you dont need fixed height.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: margin: auto 0 does also work if I do not have any margins specified. It just sets auto margins on top and bottom

Comment: I have edited the answer. What I meant to say was you cant center inline elements with margins.